# Prove that there exists $k>1$ and $x_1, x_2, \dots ,x_k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^k\phi(x_i)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^kx_i$ are both $n$th powers of an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I got an interesting question which asks

> Consider a fixed positive integer $n>1$. Prove that there exists an
> integer $k>1$ and distinct integers $x_1, x_2, \dots ,x_k$, all
> greater than $1$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^k\phi(x_i)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^kx_i$ are both $n$th powers of an integer. Here $\phi$ is the Euler
> totient function.

I am familiar with the basic elementary properties of the $\phi$ function, and I tried to write down the elaborate formula of $\phi(n)$ and manipulate the two sums to arrive at a conclusion. But that didn't help. Things became too ugly too soon. I also tried to look at $\sum_{i=1}^k(\phi(x_i)-x_i)$ but couldn't proceed anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting indeed to me.

Comment: @Spectre same here

Comment: but I am still at the basics in number theory, so I may not be able to answer it.

Comment: @Spectre Considering the source of this question, I don't think you need very advanced number theory to solve it. I think, we need an intelligent trick or something like that.

Comment: @SayanDutta What is the source?

Comment: @VIVID An inter-college maths competition, the syllabus of which do not contain very advanced number theory.

Comment: Any idea for a simple(?) subproblem, e.g., that there are infiniely many solutions for $n=2$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen nope! I don't have any intuition about this one.

Answer (score 1):

Select a provisional set of values $y_1=3,y_2=5,\dots,y_k=2k+1$ and let the sum of those values of $\varphi(y_i)$ be equal to $S$. If $S$ is not perfect $n$'th power let $m$ be the difference to the next perfect $n$'th power and write $m$ as a sum of $d$ powers of $2:$ $2^{a_1},2^{a_2},\dots,2^{a_d}$ and let $y_{k+i} = 2^{a_i+1}$. Note that $m<k^2$ for large values of $k$.

At this point we have $k+d$ distinct values such that the sum of the values of $\varphi(y_i)$ is a perfect $n$'th power.

What we are going to do to make the sum of the $x_i$ also a perfect $n$'th power is select some of the initial $k$ values $x_i$ to be $y_i$ and some $2y_i$, and let $x_{k+i} = y_{k+i}$ for $i>0$. So we are going to be taking $k+d$ values $x_i$.

By doing this the sum of the values of $\varphi(x_i)$ is equal to the sum of values of $\varphi(y_i)$ and hence is a perfect $n$'th power, and the sum of the values of $x_i$ can be equal to $s+ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+d}y_i$ where $s$ is the sum of any subset of $\{3,5,\dots,2k+1\}$

We can show that for $k\geq 10$ every $s$ in the range $[8,k^2/10]$ is possible by induction.

Since we have that $t=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+d}y_i$ is at most $2k^2$ for large $k$, it follows that for large $k$ there is a perfect $n$'th power in the range $[t+8,t+k^2/10]$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "write $m$ as the sum of $d$ powers of $i$"? I didn't get that part.

Comment: It should have said write $m$ as a sum of $d$ powers of $2$. @SayanDutta

Comment: @SayanDutta is there a step that doesn't convince you?

Comment: No, it's not about a step. Actually, I can't get the whole idea :( Can you repeat the same thing using $n=20$ please? I think, that would help.

Comment: If I change $n$ with $20$ then I just need to change $4$ numbers in the solution, it will read the exact same.